# How to show/hide a specific image based on which checkbox is clicked (clicking cbox3 should open tinypic3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have 10 different checkboxes, each with their unique ID - in sequential order like: `cbox1`, `cbox2`, etc.. Each checkbox has an associated "tinybox" div which contains an image, and each image has an ID also in sequential order, like `tinypic1`, `tinypic2`, etc.. I'm trying to write a jQuery script so that when a user clicks on any of the checkboxes, it will then either `.show()` or `.hide()` that associated tinypic.

For example, let's say a user clicks on the third checkbox, which has id="cbox3", the script should identify this is cbox THREE and therefore show or hide "tinypic3". Each checkbox has a unique ID, but has the same Class (called cboxes).

This jQuery script successfully uses the class to run when any cbox is clicked, but how do I get it to show/hide the associated TINYPIC instead of show/hiding the cbox itself?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.cboxes').click(function() {
 if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
           $(this).next().show();  // This should show the associated tinypic with the same number as the cbox that was clicked.
            }   
        else {
            $(this).next().hide();    // This should hide the associated tinypic with the same number as the cbox that was clicked.
        }
     });    
   });       
</script>
```

I've tried substituting `$(this).next().show();` for `$("[id^='tinypic']").show();`  or `$('input:checkbox[id^="tinypic_"]')` but it won't work. I'm obviously not understanding the logic somehow.

Any help is huge! Thanks a lot :)

**Here's a sample checkbox for cbox2:**

```
<li>
   <input id="cbox2" type="checkbox" name="cbox2" class="cboxes" />
   <label for="cbox2">Show</label>  
   <div class="tinybox">
      <img src="http://www.example.com/img/temp.jpg" alt="tinypic2" id="tinypic2" style="display:none;">   
   </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxvjyvxx/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.cboxes').change(function() {
       var image = $(this).siblings(".tinybox").find("img");
       if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
           image.show();  // This should show the associated tinypic with the same number as the cbox that was clicked.
       }   
       else {
          image.hide();    // This should hide the associated tinypic with the same number as the cbox that was clicked.
       }
   });    
 });
```

So first we should use `change` event instead of click to handle not only clicks but any changes.
Secondly we should not operate only next item but find sibling by class if html changes we don't need to change the JS code.
And at the end when we find this element we should search within it for image to show it or hide based on checkbox checked state, here we can even improve my code

here is an updated version of [jsfillde](http://jsfiddle.net/bxvjyvxx/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.cboxes').change(function() {
       var image = $(this).siblings(".tinybox").find("img");
       image.toggle($(this).prop('checked'));
   });    
 });
```

Comment: I'm running out the door but will report back soon, and give credit where due. Thanks :)

Comment: Your updated fiddle worked perfectly, very simple and straight forward. I appreciate the explanation of the difference between change and check, so I gave you the magical green check mark. Thanks Eugene.

Answer (score 1):

JSfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/evjkvur1/

```
 $(this).next() //refers to the label and not the image,
 Try giving
 $(this).closest("li").find("img");
```

Comment: I'm running out the door but will report back soon, and give credit where due. Thanks :)

Comment: This solution also works perfectly, however I used Eugene's answer as I believe `$('.cboxes').change(function() {` is a better option that `.click()` but you deserve recognition. So thanks Ramanathan!

Answer (score 1):

This example will allow you to place the `tinybox` divs anywhere you want on the page, and show/hide them as appropriate.

We use a separator character (the "_") to make it easy to split-off the numeric identifier from the rest of the ID. Alternately, if you cannot refactor your ID tags, you can use the `slice()` method, thus:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var i = this.id.slice(-2).replace( /\D+/g, '');
    alert(i);
});
```

Instead of using `.show()` / `.hide()`, which you probably know well, I used the `.animate()` method to change the opacity, for two reasons: (1) to demonstrate how it works, and (2) just to keep the DIVs in position (since the element isn't removed from the flow, it is only rendered invisible)

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6bz80myg/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
CB 1: <input type="checkbox" id="cb_1" /><br>
CB 2: <input type="checkbox" id="cb_2" /><br>
<div id="tinypic_1"><img src="http://placekitten.com/50/51" /></div>
<div id="tinypic_2"><img src="http://placekitten.com/48/50" /></div>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var i = this.id.split('_')[1]; //split into array at the _ & choose 2nd element
    var vis = ( $(this).prop('checked') ) ? 1 : 0; //1=checked, 0=not
    $('#tinypic_'+i+' img').animate({
        'opacity' : vis
    },800);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
div{display:inline-block;margin:10px;}
img{opacity:0;}
```

Comment: Wow, what a detailed answer! I tried it out and it does work for me but isn't the exact solution I was looking for. It goes above and beyond the call of duty so I chose Eugene's answer instead, but you deserve a huge thank you for explaining how your solution worked - I learned a lot. Thanks a ton, take care.

Comment: Very pleased the answer was helpful to you. Bookmark and revisit answers that you find illuminating. Soon you will be using the tricks yourself -- like the ternary operator, for eg. *And thanks for the upvote - always good to upvote whenever appropriate. Costs nothing, and is helpful to the responder.*